# OpenTK.Core | Does not detect my keypresses

Tags: c#, .net, windows, opengl, opentk

I am following this tutorial to learn how to use OpenGL in C#. Everything ran fine until this part: [OpenGL 4 with OpenTK in C# Part 10: Asteroid Invaders](http://dreamstatecoding.blogspot.com/2017/02/opengl-4-with-opentk-in-c-part-10.html). I am not using the exact same OpenTK as the one used in the tutorial. I am using this version that is compatible with .NET Core here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTK.NETCore/

## Issue

Seems that OpenTK does not detect my keyboard. I have a simple update loop that handles keyboard input like this:

OnUpdateFrame

```
protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUpdateFrame(e);
    this.HandleKeyboard(e.Time);
    // {...} Update Logic
}
```

HandleKeyboard

```
protected void HandleKeyboard(double delta)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Handling keyboard");
    var keyState = this.Keyboard.GetState();
    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape))
    {
        this.Exit();
    }
    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Moving left");
        this.player.MoveLeft();
    }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.D)          {
        Console.WriteLine("Moving right");
        this.player.MoveRight();
    }
    if (!this.gameOver && keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.Space) && this.lastKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Key.Space))  
    {
        this.gameObjects.Add(this.gameObjectFactory.CreateBullet(this.player.Position));
    }
    this.lastKeyboardState = keyState;
}
```

The console shows `Handling keyboard` many times, when I press `A` or `D` it doesn't write `Moving left` or `Moving right`. When I debug, and hover over `keystate` there is a property `IsConnected = false`. Maybe OpenTK is not recognizing my keyboard?
I am using the laptop keyboard so nothing fancy.

According to the documentation on Keyboard.GetState() it says `Gets the primary Keyboard device, or null if no keyboard exists`. But it doesn't return null?

How can I solve this? Thanks

## Minimal example

I tried this on a separate solution:

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Input;

namespace OpenTKTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var window = new GameWindow())
            {
                window.UpdateFrame += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    var state = window.Keyboard.GetState();
                    if (state.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("KEYSTATE");
                    }
                };
                window.KeyDown += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    if (eventArgs.Key == Key.A)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("KEYDOWN EVENT");
                    }
                };
                window.Run(60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And effectively, when I press the `A` key, `KEYDOWN EVENT` gets written but not `KEYSTATE`. So definitely a bug.

Comment: It seems that the `KeyState` does not work properly. When I add a `this.KeyDown += Game_KeyDown` and have it write something on the console it works. I guess I will have to write my own KeyState class that I fill myself until then..

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather (having experienced similar results), `OpenTK.Input.Keyboard` API is not yet implemented.